# I am having problem uploading user data on firestore during time of registration using firebase authentication

Tags: java, android, google-cloud-firestore, firebase-authentication

```
import androidx.annotation.NonNull;
import androidx.annotation.RequiresApi;
import androidx.appcompat.app.AppCompatActivity;


import android.content.Intent;
import android.os.Build;
import android.os.Bundle;
import android.util.Patterns;
import android.view.View;
import android.widget.Button;
import android.widget.EditText;
import android.widget.Toast;

import com.google.android.gms.tasks.OnCompleteListener;
import com.google.android.gms.tasks.OnFailureListener;
import com.google.android.gms.tasks.OnSuccessListener;
import com.google.android.gms.tasks.Task;
import com.google.firebase.auth.AuthResult;
import com.google.firebase.auth.FirebaseAuth;
import com.google.firebase.firestore.CollectionReference;
import com.google.firebase.firestore.DocumentReference;
import com.google.firebase.firestore.FieldValue;
import com.google.firebase.firestore.FirebaseFirestore;

import java.util.HashMap;
import java.util.Map;

public class Register extends AppCompatActivity {
    Button btn2_signup;
    Button btn_login;
    EditText e_mail, pass_word,phone_number;
    public EditText user_name;
    FirebaseAuth mAuth;
    FirebaseFirestore fStore;



    public static String username;
    String userID;

    @RequiresApi(api = Build.VERSION_CODES.N)
    @Override
    protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
        setContentView(R.layout.activity_register);
        e_mail=findViewById(R.id.email);
        pass_word=findViewById(R.id.password1);
        user_name=findViewById(R.id.username);
        phone_number=findViewById(R.id.phone_number);
        btn2_signup=findViewById(R.id.sign);
        btn_login = findViewById(R.id.login);
        mAuth=FirebaseAuth.getInstance();



        btn2_signup.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
            @Override
            public void onClick(View v) {
                String email = e_mail.getText().toString().trim();
                String password= pass_word.getText().toString().trim();
                if(email.isEmpty())
                {
                    e_mail.setError("Email is empty");
                    e_mail.requestFocus();
                    return;
                }
                if(!Patterns.EMAIL_ADDRESS.matcher(email).matches())
                {
                    e_mail.setError("Enter the valid email address");
                    e_mail.requestFocus();
                    return;
                }
                if(password.isEmpty())
                {
                    pass_word.setError("Enter the password");
                    pass_word.requestFocus();
                    return;
                }
                if(password.length()<6)
                {
                    pass_word.setError("Length of the password should be more than 6");
                    pass_word.requestFocus();
                    return;
                }
                mAuth.createUserWithEmailAndPassword(email,password).addOnCompleteListener(new OnCompleteListener<AuthResult>() {
                    @Override
                    public void onComplete(@NonNull Task<AuthResult> task) {
                        if(task.isSuccessful())
                        {
                            username = user_name.getText().toString();

                            Toast.makeText(Register.this,"You are successfully Registered", Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();

                            Intent i = new Intent(Register.this,Login.class);
                            startActivity(i);
                        }
                        else
                        {
                            Toast.makeText(Register.this,"You are not Registered! Try again",Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
                        }
                    }
                });

            }
        });

        btn_login.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
            @Override
            public void onClick(View v) {
                Intent i = new Intent(Register.this,Login.class);
                startActivity(i);
            }
        });

    }



    public void uploadUserData(){
        String email = e_mail.getText().toString();
        String phoneNumber = phone_number.getText().toString();
        userID = mAuth.getCurrentUser().getUid();
        CollectionReference collectionReference = fStore.collection("Users data");
        Map<String,Object> user = new HashMap<>();
        user.put("timestamp", FieldValue.serverTimestamp());
        user.put("userid",userID);
        user.put("email",email);
        user.put("phoneNumber",phoneNumber);


        collectionReference.add(user)
                .addOnSuccessListener(new OnSuccessListener<DocumentReference>() {
                    @Override
                    public void onSuccess(DocumentReference documentReference) {

                    }
                })
                .addOnFailureListener(new OnFailureListener() {
                    @Override
                    public void onFailure(@NonNull Exception e) {
                        Toast.makeText(getApplicationContext(),"Error!",Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
                        //Log.w(TAG, "Error!", e);
                    }
                });
    }
}
```

I want to upload the user data on firestore during the time of registration of user using firebase authentication. I have created a method called uploadUserData() but when its called from createUserWithEmailAndPassword in onComplete method the app stops. Can someone please point out the errors in code and the changes required.

Comment: In using just showing code its not suitable to answer . for using firebase you have to set up the environment setup for firebase authentication.

Comment: All setup for firebase and firestore is done. I am only having problem in uploading data from register page rest pages are working fine with firestore

Comment: environment setup for firebase authentication. 
1. connect your project with firebase 
2.Add dependency properly 
 the main thing is You have to find your project sha code by using this code you have to download a json file , name like google_services.json and paste it in your project src folder..

Comment: if your code is ok then you  have problem with environment setup to upload data in firebase .

Comment: 1. in `onComplete`, task is succeful? 2. where do you call `uploadUserData`?

Comment: The problem is only when I call this method uploadUserData()which I created.When the method is called from task.isSuccessfull then the error appers. I need to find error in method declaration

Comment: add a break point and debud the code to see exactly where it crashes

Comment: @Avital onComplete is successfull and uploadUserData is called from task.isSuccessful  in createUserWithEmailAndPassword

Comment: It crashes after creating a email and password in the uploadUserData method

Comment: have you see your error on logcat?

Comment: try remove the startActivity

Comment: Where are you calling `uploadUserData()` method?

Comment: @AlexMamo before starting the intent for login activity

Comment: Without seeing the code it's hard to help.

Comment: I will share the github repo soon . Your help is much needed

Comment: @ARSALAN AHMAD 74 did you try remove the startActivity? don't switch activity before you finish updating firebase

Comment: @Avital Where will I start the intent then??

Comment: @ARSALANAHMAD74 inside `uploadUserData()`, after updating firebase